# Changing CSS of element inside an iframe using data attribute

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, iframe

I have an `iframe` inside my HTML document. This `iframe` has the data attribute "`data-search-id`" which is "`mainline-top`". How do I use JavaScript outside the iframe to change the color of the element with class "`base-top`". Should I use the data attribute or is there another way? Note I can't add an id or class to the iframe, it is being loaded from somewhere else.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Page Title</title>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js "integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<body>

    <iframe data-search-id="mainline-top">
        
        <style>.base-top{color: #red;}</style>
        
        <div class="base-top">Stuff</div>

    </iframe> 

<script>
     $('.base-top.).css(color, "blue");
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The iframe is coming from another domain, but I think I can edit it, I just have to access the iframe with the data attribute

Comment: var iframe = document.querySelctor("[data-search-id='mainline-top']"); or something like that?

Comment: *"iframe is coming from another domain"*. Then you can not get inside it  with script from parent page  due to browser security restrictions

Answer (score -1):

You can insert style tag into iframe.

```
<iframe data-search-id="mainline-top" id="myIframe">
        
        <style>.base-top{color: red;}</style>
        
        <div class="base-top">Stuff</div>

    </iframe> 
<style type="text/css" id="mycss">.base-top{color: blue;}</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('*[data-search-id="mainline-top"]').contents().find("head")[0].appendChild(mycss);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Perfect, how do I do it with the iframe's data attribute? I can't give the iframe an ID or else I would

Comment: use can use : $('*[data-search-id="mainline-top"]')

Comment: When I try it out in jsfiddle it doesn't seem to work

Comment: If the source of the iframe has a different source or protocol (http://, https://), then you can not access it at all with anything.

Comment: If I can get your example to work first then I can test it. Is there a way to run your code snippet to try it out? When I copy/pasted it into JS fiddle the contents().find("head") part doesnt work. But doing $('*[data-search-id="mainline-top"]').hide(); does work

Comment: This will not work on cross origin iframe. @Reddy You are confusing hiding the iframe element itself with elements inside the iframe window which is inaccessible

Comment: @Reddy that's because it was the same css . i changed it , you can test now 
here is link : https://jsfiddle.net/th67jpde/